# RandomInt is throwing a value error, do I have an order of operations wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tuples

I'm trying to display a random tuple(0) item on the click of the 'next' button, but it keeps throwing a value error. I feel as though everything is there, I just need to swap some code around.

I've done my best to swap things around, and declare variables in different spots, to no avail.

My error code is:

```
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, 0, 0)
```

My program code is:

```py
    #Import
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from random import randint
    
    #Define Tkinter Variables
    root = Tk()
    
    #Define user created variables
    AcronymList = []
    DefinitionList = []
    TupleItemCount = 0
    global FileInfo
    
    #Tkinter Setup
    root.title("Acronym Flash Cards")
    root.iconbitmap("flashcards.ico")
    root.geometry("650x450")
    mainMenu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=mainMenu)
    
    def openFile(filename, list):
        Text_File = open(filename, 'r+') #Open and store text file as list
        global TextFileLineCount
        TextFileLineCount = Text_File.readlines()#Count the lines in the file
        for line in TextFileLineCount:
            list.append(line.strip())  # Removes unneccessary garbage
        Text_File.close()
        if list == AcronymList:
            print("Acronym list text file to list variable success!\nDirectory and file name: ", str(filename))
        else:
            print("Definition list text file to list variable success!\nDirectory and file name: ", str(filename))
        if (AcronymList and DefinitionList):
            MergeListsToTuple()
    
    def MergeListsToTuple():
        global ListTuple
        ListTuple = []
        for i in range(len(TextFileLineCount)):
            ListTuple.append((AcronymList[i],DefinitionList[i]))
            i += 1
        TupleItemCount = len(ListTuple)
        print()
        print("Tuple Created!")
    
    def GetWordListInfo():
        FileInfo = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="/", title="Open File..", filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt")])
        WordListDir = FileInfo.name
        openFile(WordListDir, AcronymList)
    
    def GetDefinitionListInfo():
        FileInfo = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="/", title="Open File..", filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt")])
        WordListDir = FileInfo.name
        openFile(WordListDir, DefinitionList)
    
    
    def Hint():
        pass
    
    def SubmitAnswer():
        pass
    
    
    #Create a menu
    fileMenu = Menu(mainMenu, tearoff=0)
    #File dropdown and choices
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Select Acronym List..", command=GetWordListInfo)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Select Definition List..", command=GetDefinitionListInfo)
    
    #Edit dropdown and choices
    editMenu = Menu(mainMenu, tearoff=0)
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
    editMenu.add_command(label="Exit..", command=root.quit)
    
    ShownAcronym = Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 30))
    ShownAcronym.pack(pady=50)
    
    AnswerLabel = Label(root, text="")
    AnswerLabel.pack(pady=20)
    
    EnterGuess = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 18))
    EnterGuess.pack(pady=20)
    
    #Create a frame for buttons to sit in - makes for easy organizing
    ButtonFrame = Frame(root)
    ButtonFrame.pack(pady=20)
    
    #Create those buttons
    HintButton = Button(ButtonFrame, text="Hint")
    HintButton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20)
    
    AnswerButton = Button(ButtonFrame, text="Answer")
    AnswerButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20)
    
    
    def NextAcronym():
        RandAcronym = randint(0, (int(TupleItemCount) - 1))
        #Update label with acronym
        AnswerLabel.config(text=ListTuple[RandomAcronym][0])
    
    
    NextButton = Button(ButtonFrame, text="Next", command=NextAcronym)
    NextButton.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20)
    
    #Hint Label
    HintLabel = Label(root, text="")
    HintLabel.pack(pady=20)
    
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  This error occurs when the first argument to `randint` is greater than the second argument.

To demonstrate:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randint(0,-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\asp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\random.py", line 370, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Users\asp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\random.py", line 353, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, 0, 0)
>>>
```

in your `nextAcronym` function you have

```
def NextAcronym():
    RandAcronym = randint(0, (int(TupleItemCount) - 1))
```

and at the top you have

```
TupleItemCount = 0
```

So when the function runs `int(TupleItemCount)` is equal to `0` and then you subtract one and it throws an error.

What you need to do is add TupleItemCount to the global decleration in the `MergeListsToTuple` function.  That way it updates the global variable when you change it inside the function scope.

```
def MergeListsToTuple():
    global ListTuple, TupleItemCount
```

Comment: I've edited my code to include the whole program
When I run the `NextAcronym` I want it to lake the length of the tuple list item count, and generate a random number to display/update the label with the corresponding item in the tuple list.

Comment: I realized I don't know how to use my own program, I need to open the files/run the functions before I can hit the 'Next' button.

Comment: @TristenC  You also need to make the edits that I suggested, there is a lot of other issues with your code as well. but what I suggested fixes this particular problem at least

Comment: I'm willing to learn if you're willing to show me the issues